# Prove that$ \int_0^\infty x^{2n}e^{-ax^2}dx = \frac{(2n-1)(2n-3) \cdots1}{2(2a)^n}\sqrt{\frac\pi a} $

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

I have the following question:

---

Verify
$
\int_0^\infty x^{2n}e^{-ax^2}dx = \frac{(2n-1)(2n-3) ... 1}{2(2a)^n}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}
$
by differentiating 
$
\int_0^\infty e^{-ax^2}dx
$
with respect to $a$, $n$ times.

---

How would I go about doing this? I am unsure how differentiating the latter integral links to the former result.

Comment: What happens when you differentiate that integral with respect to $a$? ie. When you differentiate under the integral sign?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for Leibniz's [differentiation under the integral sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) rule.

We know that

$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-ax^2} \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}.$$

Differentiating with respect to $a$ gives us

$$\int_0^{\infty} -x^2 e^{-ax^2} \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \left( - \frac{1}{2} \right) \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a^3}},$$

or

$$\int_0^{\infty} x^2 e^{-ax^2} \, dx = \frac{1}{4a} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}.$$

By repeated application of the method you'll arrive at the answer.

Comment: More information on this topic can be found [here](http://fy.chalmers.se/~tfkhj/FeynmanIntegration.pdf).

Comment: @Lucian The link is not opening for me.

Comment: It was operational only a couple of weeks ago... Most probably the problem is only temporary. In the meantime, try [this](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-304-undergraduate-seminar-in-discrete-mathematics-spring-2006/projects/integratnfeynman.pdf).